# Overloading multiple variadic constructors

Tags: c++

I have a template class where one of the constructors has variadic arguments. Recently I added another variadic constructor, however invoking the original variadic constructor causes compile time errors due to ambiguous function overload calls.

The class looks something like

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int num_args, ...)
    {
        //implementation
    }

    MyClass(MyClass<T> old, int num_args, ...)
    {
    //implementation
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> m = MyClass<int>(5,2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Both of these and other constructors work by themselves, however calling the first constructor when the definition of the second constructor is included refuses to compile because of ambiguity. Is there any way to have multiple constructors with variadic arguments in C++? Alternatively, is there a better way of doing what the code above is trying to do?

Comment: I can't find a problem with this, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5uBtLUYZCPguJBhL.  What compiler and command line switches are you using?

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It crashes now. If I want to force the same template how would I enforce that?

Comment: you need to create a [mre]

Comment: The code as it is does crash...

Comment: let me say that again: you need to post a [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use varargs. It's a relic from C and template variadic arguments are better in every single way.

That being said, the problem is that an int can be converted to `MyClass<T>` due to the first constructor and since it involves just one user conversion it is a viable choice for the second constructor.

One solution is to make the ctor(s) explicit:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
explicit MyClass(int num_args, ...);

MyClass(MyClass<T> old, int num_args, ...);
};
```

You can make the 2nd one explicit if you feel so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why are template variadic arguments better?

Comment: @nevets they are type safe. you don't need to specify a mechanism for their numbers. They play well with template metaprogramming. There isn't any one motive to use varargs except for legacy code and in special cases where you want to construct an overload that will be picked last.